# Draft.js change default monospace font

Tags: css, reactjs, draftjs

By default Draft Editor uses the default system monospace. I was wondering if they was a way to change it to Consolas through Draft.css or using global css classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root element of the editor component has `DraftEditor-root` class.

[image]

You can use this class name to specify styles this way:

```
.DraftEditor-root {
  font-family: Consolas;
  // other styles thay you want:
  font-size: 24px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Check the demo below, In this example, I used "Arial" font-family, with "Consolas" it works similarly:

```js
const {Editor, EditorState, ContentState} = Draft;

class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromText('Arial font-family'))
    };
  }
  
  _handleChange = (editorState) => {
    this.setState({ editorState });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <Editor 
        placeholder="Type away :)"
        editorState={this.state.editorState}
        onChange={this._handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Container />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```css
.DraftEditor-root {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 24px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/draft-js/0.7.0/Draft.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/draft-js/0.10.0/Draft.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```